# Keras with Theano backend: custom loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, theano, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to create a custom loss function in Keras for a one-layer LSTM regression problem that calculates the mean squared error between only the nonzero values in the label/truth vector, and the corresponding values in the predicted vector. I have tried doing the following

```
import theano.tensor as T
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss_func(y_true, y_pred):

    #make the prediction vector zero where the label vector is zero
    y_pred = T.where(T.eq(y_true,0), 0, y_pred) 

    #get nonzero values
    nonzero_vals = T.flatnonzero(y_pred)

    #return mean squared error on only the nonzero values
    return K.sum(K.square(y_pred-y_true)) / K.shape(nonzero_vals)[0]
```

which yields the error

> "theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start
>   from 0), used to compute Elemwise{neq,no_inplace}(/masking_1_input,
>   InplaceDimShuffle{x,x,x}.0), was not provided and not given a value.
>   Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high', for more information
>   on this error."

This does not appear to work and I think it is due to the "shape" factor of the nonzero vector. I can't seem to gather from the Theano documentation how to fit the shape value into an expression. Any help appreciated, thank you!